# file_get_contents() failed to open stream: Operation timed out... only on server

Tags: php, server, file-get-contents, php-7.2

When I try to fetch data from website on localhost or on other server, it actually loads the data, but when I try it on production server it returns the warning:

> "Warning: file_get_contents(...): failed to open stream: Operation timed out"

But this only happens on that server.
The biggest problem is that it was working yesterday without a problem.

I've already looked up `"allow_url_fopen"` in php.ini, but it was already on. I tried to use cURL but without success.

```php
try {
    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.orsr.sk/hladaj_subjekt.asp?OBMENO=$meno&PF=0&R=on");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
echo $html;
```

On localhost and my other server it shows the website, but on that server it catches error

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.orsr.sk/hladaj_subjekt.asp?OBMENO=Example&PF=0&R=on): failed to open stream: Operation timed out in

Comment: Sounds like a network level issue. Perhaps blocked traffic, or DNS resolution issue? Hard to tell. Can you ping the host and check the port availability from the server?

Comment: Then it looks like the issue is specific to your Production server. Which means we are at a bit of a disadvantage here as we cannot access that server to examine whats goin on

Comment: what happens when you prepend @ to the function? This is done to ignore the error: `$html = @file_get_contents("url here")`? Or you could try to make curl request instead of using `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Try with curl maybe can get